# get_text() or text property is not working for labels

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I want to access the text of labels, but neither `get_text()` nor `text` property is working for the following HTML:

```
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="BATSMC">
BATS Multicast PITCH
</label>
```

For example, here I want to get the value: `BATS Multicast PITCH`.

In Selenium-Python code:

```
print e.text
```

is giving blank spaces and `get_text()` is giving the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

I am getting the correct web element and am able to access other properties like size, location, parent etc. I expected  "text" to work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

The `<label>` tag in the above HTML does not have a text attribute.

If you want to retrieve the `BATS Multicast PITCH` string, then you need to get it from the `<input>` tag instead. For example, the following code will print this string:

```
e = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('input')
print e.text
```

If you want to retrieve the **entire** inner HTML of the `<label>` tag, then you can use:

```
e = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('label')
print e.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

This will print `"<input type="checkbox" value="BATSMC">BATS Multicast PITCH`.

Of course, you probably have other `<label>` and `<input>` tags in your HTML, so you'll need to use a different method (other than `find_element_by_tag_name`) in order to find these specific elements.

BTW, I just noticed that the `<input>` tag in the HTML above is not properly closed...

Comment: <input> is also giving "blank" values. Yaa, <input> is not closed and is like this. Any other solutions ?

Comment: Did you try `get_attribute('innerHTML')` for both elements?

Comment: get_attribute('innerHTML') worked for <label> and returned full value <input value="BATSYMC" type="checkbox"> 
BATS Y Multicast PITCH .............which can be parsed further while get_attribute('innerHTML') for <input> it is giving Blank/ null value ? WOuld you suggest something else or I should go ahead and parse the first one ?

Comment: Well I think it pretty much proves that the `<input>` tag not properly closed is a problem (otherwise, `get_attribute('innerHTML')` would have worked for this tag as well).

Answer (score 0):

Try use the `innerText` attribute to get only the text within the label tag.

```
e = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('label')
print e.get_attribute('innerText')
```

Comment: It resulted into "None".